# Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $t_1, t_2, t_3,..., t_n \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$ satisfy...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been struggling for about 5 days to solve this problem, but, so far, I don't even have a starting point. Could you give me a hint, or tell me how you would approach it?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality must be involved.

Comment: Source of this problem?

Comment: I don't know the exact source, one friend told me about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denote: $S_a=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}t_k^a$, for $a \in \{-1,1,2\}$

Given: $S_2S_{-1}=2S_1,S_1S_{-1}=\frac{3n^2}{2}$ and $H(t_1,t_2,...t_n)=\frac{n}{S_{-1}}$

We need to show that:
$$\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{t_k^3}{S_2-t_k^2} \geq \frac{n^2}{2S_{-1}}$$
We have:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{t_k^3}{S_2-t_k^2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{t_k^2}{\frac{S_2}{t_k}-t_k} \geq \frac{\bigg( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} t_k\bigg)^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{S_2}{t_k}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}t_k}$$
$$=\frac{S_1^2}{S_2S_{-1}-S_1} =\frac{S_1^2}{2S_1-S_1}=S_1>\frac{S_1}{3}=\frac{n^2}{2S_{-1}}$$

Comment: What does $H(...)$ mean?

Comment: In your problem, $H(...)$ denotes the harmonic average of $t_1,t_2,...t_n$